# DeckGL & Mapbox: How access ref element on map movement?

Tags: reactjs, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, deck.gl, react-map-gl

I'm trying to `console.log` the bounds of a Mapbox map in my React app every time I move around the map.

Here's my current attempt:

```
return (
    <>
      <DeckGL
        layers={layers}
        initialViewState={INITIAL_VIEW_STATE}
        controller={true}
        onViewStateChange={stateChangeFunc}
      >
        <ReactMapGL
          reuseMaps
          mapStyle={mapStyle}
          preventStyleDiffing={true}
          ref={(ref) => console.log(ref.getMap().getBounds())}
          mapboxApiAccessToken={token}
        />
      </DeckGL>
    </>
  );
```

The bounds are printed when the map loads, but I'm having trouble printing when moving around the map. Is there a `prop` that I should use to access this functionality? Putting `ref={(ref) => console.log(ref.getMap().getBounds())}` in `DeckGL` doesn't work. Is there a prop equivalent to `onViewStateChange` for `ReactMapGL`? That might allow me to create a function that prints out the `ref`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

- Listen `onViewStateChange` directly from deck (recommended using some debounce)
- Access `viewState`
- Use `getBounds` method from `WebMercatorViewport` class

```js
import DeckGL, {WebMercatorViewport} from 'deck.gl';

function debounce(fn, ms) {
  let timer;
  return (...args) => {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(() => {
      timer = null;
      fn.apply(this, args);
    }, ms);
  };
}

function handleViewStateChange({ viewState }) {
  const bounds = new WebMercatorViewport(viewState).getBounds();
  console.log(bounds);
};

<DeckGL
  ...
  onViewStateChange={debounce(handleViewStateChange, 500)}
/>
```